# Tryparse datetime string to datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse `"31.01.2017 07:56:29.470000000"`date time string into datetime format.

Code used:

```
   DateTime requiredDate;
    string date = "31.01.2017 07:56:29.470000000";

    DateTime.TryParseExact(date,
                           "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fffffff",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out requiredDate);
```

NOTE: date string is exact "31.01.2017 07:56:29.470000000", however if I use "31.01.2017 07:56:29.4700000" then it is working fine.

Please parse "31.01.2017 07:56:29.470000000".

Comment: Is DateTime.TryParseExact returning false or throwing an exception? if the latter, what is the exception?

Comment: there is no exception, but parsing did not successful.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's not the only issue here. Even if it matches, it returns false. I believe that there is a maximum number of `f`s that is allowed. Most likely, the OP needs to preprocess the string

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, I have tried with exact ``f``s however, if I use 7 ``f``s and in my date I pass 7 digits, then parsing is successfull.....but i require 9 digits

Comment: 9 digits? Is this kind of precision exists?

Comment: @shash678, In a nano second Light move 30 cm. I mean I am not sure there is a instrument that know the difference between 1 nano and 2 nano seconds.

Comment: @DragandDrop Sorry I was not referencing your comment, just I thought that the title of the question was a little vague. Since there are a lot of beginner question with similar titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the maximum allowed number of `f`s in your parse string: The maximum value is `fffffff` (7 fractions). Your string contains 9 of them.

You can find this limitation in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). It mentions all possible values between `f` and `fffffff`, but not further.

Comment: Yes, with 7 it is working fine, but as per the documents received from third person we have to make it with 9 digits. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you have to trim the end yourself.

Comment: Yes I agree, because I also found 7 f only....so should I intimate client for the same that till 7 its possible?

Comment: Gaurav: there has to be some hard coded/hardware limit to the precision, and it looks like you have hit it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the number of `f` which as a maximum of 7. You are using the Round-trip date/time pattern that complies with ISO 8601. Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip).

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'**fffffff**K" custom format string for DateTime values and to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'**fffffff**zzz" custom format string for DateTimeOffset values.

As you can see, there are only 7 digits of `f` in the format indicated by the documentation.

To solve your problem you should remove the last 2 digit from your input.